# Simplifying the modulus square $|a_{+}b_{+}^{\ast} e^{ix} + a_{-}b_{-}^{\ast} e^{iy}|^{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a_{+},a_{-},b_{+},b_{-} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. In addition to this, I have the constraints:

$|a_{+}|^{2} + |a_{-}|^{2} = 1$

$|b_{+}|^{2} + |b_{-}|^{2} = 1$

$\ $

Define the quantity  $Z := a_{+}b_{+}^{\ast} e^{ix} + a_{-}b_{-}^{\ast} e^{iy}$

I'm trying to compute $|Z|^{2}$ (really I want a simpler looking expression).

My computation:

$ |Z|^{2} = \left( a_{+}b_{+}^{\ast} e^{ix} + a_{-}b_{-}^{\ast} e^{iy} \right) \left( a_{+}^{\ast}b_{+} e^{-ix} + a_{-}^{\ast}b_{-} e^{-iy} \right)$

$=|a_{+}|^{2}|b_{+}|^{2} + a_{+}a_{-}^{\ast}b_{+}^{\ast}b_{-}e^{i(x-y)} + a_{+}^{\ast}a_{-}b_{+}b_{-}^{\ast}e^{-i(x-y)} + |a_{-}|^{2}|b_{-}|^{2} $

$=|a_{+}|^{2}|b_{+}|^{2} + \left[ a_{+}a_{-}^{\ast}b_{+}^{\ast}b_{-}e^{i(x-y)} \right] + \left[ a_{+}a_{-}^{\ast}b_{+}^{\ast}b_{-}e^{i(x-y)} \right]^{\ast} + |a_{-}|^{2}|b_{-}|^{2} $

$=|a_{+}|^{2}|b_{+}|^{2} + 2 \mathrm{Re}\left( a_{+}a_{-}^{\ast}b_{+}^{\ast}b_{-}e^{i(x-y)} \right) + |a_{-}|^{2}|b_{-}|^{2} $

Is there a cleaner way of writing this? Perhaps not involving the $\mathrm{Re}(\cdot)$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

When $\text{z}_1\space\wedge\space\text{z}_2\space\wedge\space\text{z}_3\space\wedge\space\text{z}_4\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\text{a}\space\wedge\space\text{b}\in\mathbb{R}$:

Simplify:

$$\left|\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}e^{\text{a}i}+\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}e^{\text{b}i}\right|^2$$

So, we get:

1. $$\text{z}_1=\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i$$
2. $$\overline{\text{z}_2}=\Re\left[\text{z}_2\right]-\Im\left[\text{z}_2\right]i$$
3. $$e^{\text{a}i}=\cos\left(\text{a}\right)+\sin\left(\text{a}\right)i$$
4. $$\text{z}_3=\Re\left[\text{z}_3\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_3\right]i$$
5. $$\overline{\text{z}_4}=\Re\left[\text{z}_4\right]-\Im\left[\text{z}_4\right]i$$
6. $$e^{\text{b}i}=\cos\left(\text{b}\right)+\sin\left(\text{b}\right)i$$
7. When $\text{s}\in\mathbb{C}$:
   $$\left|\text{s}\right|^2=\left|\Re\left[\text{s}\right]+\Im\left[\text{s}\right]i\right|^2=\left(\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{s}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{s}\right]}\right)^2=\Re^2\left[\text{s}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{s}\right]$$

With your constraints, we also get:

- $$\left|\text{z}_1\right|^2+\left|\text{z}_3\right|^2=\Re^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Re^2\left[\text{z}_3\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_3\right]=1$$
- $$\left|\text{z}_2\right|^2+\left|\text{z}_4\right|^2=\Re^2\left[\text{z}_2\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_2\right]+\Re^2\left[\text{z}_4\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_4\right]=1$$

And use:

- $$\Re\left[\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}\right]=\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]\Re\left[\text{z}_2\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_2\right]$$
- $$\Im\left[\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}\right]=\Re\left[\text{z}_2\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_2\right]$$
- $$\Re\left[\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}\right]=\Re\left[\text{z}_3\right]\Re\left[\text{z}_4\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_3\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_4\right]$$
- $$\Im\left[\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}\right]=\Re\left[\text{z}_4\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_3\right]-\Re\left[\text{z}_3\right]\Im\left[\text{z}_4\right]$$

---

So, you need to solve:

$$\color{red}{\left|\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}e^{\text{a}i}+\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}e^{\text{b}i}\right|^2=\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}e^{\text{a}i}\right]+\Re\left[\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}e^{\text{b}i}\right]\right)^2+\left(\Im\left[\text{z}_1\overline{\text{z}_2}e^{\text{a}i}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_3\overline{\text{z}_4}e^{\text{b}i}\right]\right)^2}$$